# Flutter SharedPreferences data limit

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I am trying to save some data in sharedPref. But seems like if the object becomes large then the sharedPref is not saving the single object. Can anyone please tell me the size limit in sharedPref of Flutter app ?

This is a part of the object which is converted to Json and trying to save in sharedPref. Many structures are remaining also.

```
    I/flutter (13111):       products: {
    I/flutter (13111):         product: {
    I/flutter (13111):           id: 116
    I/flutter (13111):           metaMerchant: {
    I/flutter (13111):             id: 3
    I/flutter (13111):             version: 1
    I/flutter (13111):             brandDisplayName: Merchant: 2
    I/flutter (13111):             logoUrls: https://brandmark.io/logo-rank/random/pepsi.png
    I/flutter (13111):             coverPhotoUrls: https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/12/15/18/store-984393_960_720.jpg
    I/flutter (13111):             businessTypes: CLOTHS
    I/flutter (13111):             businessLocation: {
    I/flutter (13111):             }
    I/flutter (13111):             businessAddress: {
    I/flutter (13111):             }
    I/flutter (13111):             businessSchedule: {
    I/flutter (13111):             }
    I/flutter (13111):             isOpenNow: true
    I/flutter (13111):             deliveryCharge: 20.0
    I/flutter (13111):             merchantTabs: {
    I/flutter (13111):               tabId: home
    I/flutter (13111):               displayName: Home
    I/flutter (13111):               groupIds: 11
    I/flutter (13111):               groupIds: 12
    I/flutter (13111):               groupIds: 13
    I/flutter (13111):               groupIds: 14
    I/flutter (13111):               groupIds: 15
    I/flutter (13111):             }
    I/flutter (13111):             merchantTabs: {
    I/flutter (13111):               tabId: home1
    I/flutter (13111):               displayName: Home1
    I/flutter (13111):               groupIds: 11
    I/flutter (13111):               groupIds: 12
    I/flutter (13111):               groupIds: 13
    I/flutter (13111):               groupIds: 14
    I/flutter (13111):               groupIds: 15
    I/flutter (13111):             }
    I/flutter (13111):             merchantTabs: {
    I/flutter (13111):               tabId: home2
    I/flutter (13111):               displayName: Home2
    I/flutter (13111):               groupIds: 11
    I/flutter (13111):               groupIds: 12
    I/flutter (13111):               groupIds: 13
    I/flutter (13111):               groupIds: 14
    I/flutter (13111):               groupIds: 15
    I/flutter (13111):             }
    I/flutter (13111):             merchantTabs: {
    I/flutter (13111):               tabId: home3
    I/flutter (13111):               displayName: Home3
    I/flutter (13111):               groupIds: 11
    I/flutter (13111):               groupIds: 12
    I/flutter (13111):               groupIds: 13
    I/flutter (13111):               groupIds: 14
    I/flutter (13111):               groupIds: 15
    I/flutter (13111):             }
    I/flutter (13111):             merchantTabs: {
    I/flutter (13111):               tabId: home4
    I/flutter (13111):               displayName: Home4
    I/flutter (13111):               groupIds: 11
    I/flutter (13111):               groupIds: 12
    I/flutter (13111):               groupIds: 13
    I/flutter (13111):               groupIds: 14
    I/flutter (13111):               groupIds: 15
    I/flutter (13111):             }
    I/flutter (13111):             merchantTabs: {
    I/flutter (13111):               tabId: home5
    I/flutter (13111):               displayName: Home5
    I/flutter (13111):               groupIds: 11
    I/flutter (13111):               groupIds: 12
    I/flutter (13111):               groupIds: 13
    I/flutter (13111):               groupIds: 14
    I/flutter (13111):               groupIds: 15
    I/flutter (13111):             }
    I/flutter (13111):           }
    I/flutter (13111):           title: Product16
    I/flutter (13111):           originalPrice: 2962.0
    I/flutter (13111):           sellingPrice: 2962.0
    I/flutter (13111):           imageUrls: https://catseye.com.bd/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/1362x1653/85e4522595efc69f496374d01ef2bf13/c/e/ce_panjabi_i14_5e2_623_8_tk_5990_1_.jpg
    I/flutter (13111):           deliveryCharge: 20.0
    I/flutter (13111):           productVariation: {
    I/flutter (13111):             variationEnable: true
    I/flutter (13111):             extensions: {
    I/flutter (13111):               id: 44228028569101
    I/flutter (13111):               title: Extension: 1
    I/flutter (13111):               merchantId: 3
    I/flutter (13111):               displayTitle: Extension: 1
    I/flutter (13111):               description: Extension 1
    I/flutter (13111):               extensionItems: {
    I/flutter (13111):                 id: 44228028548389
    I/flutter (13111):                 itemTitle: ExtensionItem: 1
    I/flutter (13111):                 extraCharge: 98.0
    I/flutter (13111):               }
    I/flutter (13111):               extensionItems: {
    I/flutter (13111):                 id: 44228028557460
    I/flutter (13111):                 itemTitle: ExtensionItem: 2
    I/flutter (13111):                 extraCharge: 42.0
    I/flutter (13111):               }
    I/flutter (13111):               extensionItems: {
    I/flutter (13111):                 id: 44228028560873
    I/flutter (13111):                 itemTitle: ExtensionItem: 3
    I/flutter (13111):                 extraCharge: 52.0
    I/flutter (13111):               }
    I/flutter (13111):               extensionItems: {
    I/flutter (13111):                 id: 44228028563518
    I/flutter (13111):                 itemTitle: ExtensionItem: 4
    I/flutter (13111):                 extraCharge: 40.0
    I/flutter (13111):               }
    I/flutter (13111):             }
    I/flutter (13111):             extensions: {
    I/flutter (13111):               id: 44228028605392
    I/flutter (13111):               title: Extension: 2
    I/flutter (13111):               merchantId: 3
    I/flutter (13111):               displayTitle: Extension: 2
    I/flutter (13111):               description: Extension 2
    I/flutter (13111):               extensionItems: {
    I/flutter (13111):                 id: 44228028589832
    I/flutter (13111):                 itemTitle: ExtensionItem: 1
    I/flutter (13111):                 extraCharge: 86.0
    I/flutter (13111):               }
    I/flutter (13111):               extensionItems: {
    I/flutter (13111):                 id: 44228028593236
    I/flutter (13111):                 itemTitle: ExtensionItem: 2
    I/flutter (13111):                 extraCharge: 57.0
    I/flutter (13111):               }
    I/flutter (13111):               extensionItems: {
    I/flutter (13111):                 id: 44228028599177
    I/flutter (13111):                 itemTitle: ExtensionItem: 3
    I/flutter (13111):                 extraCharge: 34.0
    I/flutter (13111):               }
    I/flutter (13111):               extensionItems: {
    I/flutter (13111):                 id: 44228028602233
    I/flutter (13111):                 itemTitle: ExtensionItem: 4
    I/flutter (13111):                 extraCharge: 28.0
    I/flutter (13111):               }
    I/flutter (13111):             }
    I/flutter (13111):             itemCombinations: {
    I/flutter (13111):               indexIds: 0
    I/flutter (13111):               indexIds: 0
    I/flutter (13111):               combinationPrice: 4409.0
    I/flutter (13111):             }
    I/flutter (13111):             itemCombinations: {
    I/flutter (13111):               indexIds: 0
    I/flutter (13111):               indexIds: 1
    I/flutter (13111):               combinationPrice: 3706.0
    I/flutter (13111):             }
    I/flutter (13111):             itemCombinations: {
    I/flutter (13111):               indexIds: 0
    I/flutter (13111):               indexIds: 2
    I/flutter (13111):               combinationPrice: 5198.0
    I/flutter (13111):             }
    I/flutter (13111):             itemCombinations: {
    I/flutter (13111):               indexIds: 0
    I/flutter (13111):               indexIds: 3
    I/flutter (13111):               combinationPrice: 1818.0
    I/flutter (13111):             }
    I/flutter (13111):             itemCombinations: {
    I/flutter (13111):               indexIds: 1
    I/flutter (13111):               indexIds: 0
    I/flutter (13111):               combinationPrice: 942.0
    I/flutter (13111):             }
    I/flutter (13111):             itemCombinations: {
    I/flutter (13111):               indexIds: 1
    I/flutter (13111):               indexIds: 1
    I/flutter (13111):               combinationPrice: 5908.0
    I/flutter (13111):             }
    I/flutter (13111):             itemCombinations: {
    I/flutter (13111):               indexIds: 1
    I/flutter (13111):               indexIds: 2
    I/flutter (13111):               combinationPrice: 1542.0
    I/flutter (13111):             }
    I/flutter (13111):             itemCombinations: {
    I/flutter (13111):               indexIds: 1
    I/flutter (13111):               indexIds: 3
    I/flutter (13111):               combinationPrice: 6495.0
    I/flutter (13111):             }
    I/flutter (13111):             itemCombinations: {
    I/flutter (13111):               indexIds: 2
    I/flutter (13111):               indexIds: 0
    I/flutter (13111):               combinationPrice: 8357.0
    I/flutter (13111):             }
    I/flutter (13111):             itemCombinations: {
    I/flutter (13111):               indexIds: 2
    I/flutter (13111):               indexIds: 1
    I/flutter (13111):               combinationPrice: 8865.0
    I/flutter (13111):             }
    I/flutter (13111):             itemCombinations: {
    I/flutter (13111):               indexIds: 2
    I/flutter (13111):               indexIds: 2
    I/flutter (13111):               combinationPrice: 3223.0
    I/flutter (13111):             }
    I/flutter (13111):             itemCombinations: {
    I/flutter (13111):               indexIds: 2
    I/flutter (13111):               indexIds: 3
    I/flutter (13111):               combinationPrice: 9546.0
    I/flutter (13111):             }
    I/flutter (13111):             itemCombinations: {
    I/flutter (13111):               indexIds: 3
    I/flutter (13111):               indexIds: 0
    I/flutter (13111):               combinationPrice: 4137.0
    I/flutter (13111):             }
    I/flutter (13111):             itemCombinations: {
    I/flutter (13111):               indexIds: 3
    I/flutter (13111):               indexIds: 1
    I/flutter (13111):               combinationPrice: 5253.0
    I/flutter (13111):             }
    I/flutter (13111):             itemCombinations: {
    I/flutter (13111):               indexIds: 3
    I/flutter (13111):               indexIds: 2
    I/flutter (13111):               combinationPrice: 1503.0
    I/flutter (13111):             }
    I/flutter (13111):             itemCombinations: {
    I/flutter (13111):               indexIds: 3
    I/flutter (13111):               indexIds: 3
    I/flutter (13111):               combinationPrice: 2174.0
    I/flutter (13111):             }
    I/flutter (13111):           }
    I/flutter (13111):         }
    I/flutter (13111):       }
```

Here is the code which sending data to sharedPref:

```
  Future<void> saveCarts(Iterable<CartOrderItem> items) async {
    try {
      final list = items.map((cart) => cart.toJsonMap()).toList();
      await Preferences.instance.setJson(CART_LIST_KEY, list);
    } catch (err) {
      print('<!> [CartRepository] saveCart(): $err');
    }
  }
```

This is the place where sharedPref is saving:

```
    import 'dart:async';
    import 'dart:convert' show json;
    import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

    export 'package:hurryup/src/strings.dart';

    class Preferences {
      Future<SharedPreferences> source() {
        return SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      }

      Future<int> getInt(String key) async {
        final pref = await source();
        return pref.getInt(key);
      }

      Future<void> setInt(String key, int value) async {
        final pref = await source();
        final result = await pref.setInt(key, value);
        if (!result) {
          throw Exception('Could not store integer');
        }
      }

      Future<String> getString(String key) async {
        final pref = await source();
        return pref.getString(key);
      }

      Future<void> setString(String key, String value) async {
        final pref = await source();
        final result = await pref.setString(key, value);
        if (!result) {
          throw Exception('Could not store string');
        }
      }

      Future<dynamic> getJson(String key) async {
        String source = await getString(key);
        if (source == null) return null;
        return json.decode(source);
      }

      Future<void> setJson(String key, dynamic jsonData) async {
        String value;
        if (jsonData != null) {
          value = json.encode(jsonData);
        }
        await setString(key, value);
      }

      // ----------------------------------------------------------------------- //
      static Preferences _instance;
      static Preferences get instance => _instance ??= Preferences();
      // ----------------------------------------------------------------------- //
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell us what kind of object you're saving.

Comment: edited my question with a data structure. Please have a review.

Comment: This is not a large object. According to my knowledge, SharedPrefs can't save objects, it can only save basic data types such as Strings, integers, boolean etc. 
I'll recommend you to convert your object into some kind of Json string and then save it in the preferences.

Comment: Yes I did that and saved. I have edited my code again.

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution?

Comment: Yes actually, it was not related to Cache Limit. I was having error in here.  cart.toJsonMap()).toList();

Answer (score 0):

If the `string` you are storing exceeds the `Integer.MAX_VALUE` it's better to save it in a `database`.

Comment: FYI: Integer.MAX_VALUE is 2147483647

Comment: How to calculate Integer.MAX_VALUE of my object ?

Comment: can you share the code where you are saving to shared preferences?

Comment: An opinion is not an answer.